# rails coffescript & haml include errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, haml

I'm using Rails 3.1 and I keep getting an error when trying to use any jQuery extension.

kintouch.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

index.html.haml

```
  = best_in_place contacts[0].label, :name, :display_as => :header_short, 
      :inner_class => "span2"
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .
```

kintouch.js error

```
  (function() {

      jQuery(function() {
        return $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'best_in_place'
      });

    }).call(this);
```

However if I hard link to the javascript extension like this:

```
%script{:src => "https://raw.github.com/bernat/best_in_place/master/lib/assets/javascripts/best_in_place.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
```

Everything seems to work.

My script files rendered:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the description with the error. Thanks

Comment: All of my jQuery addons are breaking...

Comment: How have you installed best_in_place.js  into your app?

Comment: Yes but something is preventing it from being loaded

Comment: View the source. Is the problem that the `<script>` tag for `best_in_place.js` comes after the `<script>` tag for `kintouch.js`? Perhaps relatedly, what's up with the indentation in your `application.js`?

Comment: my order on the server goes jquery -> best in place -> and then kintouch.js. It worked before I converted everything to haml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery was being loaded twice and thus over riding bootstrap.